# What is the best software for visual effects?

Tags: visual-effects

I want to gain some recognition by making some short films and youtube videos. I pretty much shot and edited movies in my mobile itself, and now planning to shift to PC which is a little more powerful in these kind of stuff........
And my question is which is the best software for adding visual effects(like gunshots, blood effects, explosion and other stuff)??
I am pretty new to this and the internet tells me to use Adobe after effects & Hilfilm Studio 4 but these are far too complicated.........
Is there and software which is easy to use and producesa good output??

Thanks for your patience in understanding my question.

Comment: The unfortunate (or maybe fortunate!) fact is that making high quality visual effects is a full-time career option. That's good news if you love doing it, but the downside is that it takes time & effort to develop the necessary skill set. By industry standards, AE and Hitfilm are the easiest software used in this job. Hitfilm is free, so my advice is start small, find some online tutorials, and make a few simple effects using Hitfilm. You may discover you enjoy the process, and that it's not really as intimidating as it seems to you right now.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is completely an opinion based question, I would still like to suggest that you should try at least After Effects first. Been using it for years, I can tell you that it is not at all a software you can categorize into 'too complicated to understand' and that too before getting your own hands on it. Adobe After Effects is fairly an easy software to understand and you can do basic YouTube videos that look professional in a week (if you spend 1 hour daily practicing it). Getting a powerful computer can be a plus as you'd feel frustrated if you'll render heavy footage on a regular computer. However, I used Adobe AE on 2GB RAM which people say is something near to highly frustrating.

My suggestion is to try AE, Hitfilm, v-ray, or even Blender. There's a big community for all these software where you can ask anything.